# Convert JSON tree nodes into final JSON recursively

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, tree, treenode

I need help to convert this json tree nodes to final json structure joining the nodes recursively. Any help is appreciated.
I need a recursively function in javascript.
Given below the sample input and output I needed.
My Input

```
{
  root: {
    parent_id: 'root',
    current_id: 'root',
    children: ['node_233443'],
    type: 'stack',
  },
  node_233443: {
    parent_id: 'root',
    current_id: 'node_233443',
    children: ['node_fdfd33', 'node_hd44d4'],
    type: 'column',
  },
  node_fdfd33: {
    parent_id: 'node_233443',
    current_id: 'node_fdfd33',
    children: [],
    type: 'text',
  },
  node_hd44d4: {
    parent_id: 'node_233443',
    current_id: 'node_hd44d4',
    children: [],
    type: 'image',
  },
};
```

My Needed output

```
{
  parent_id: 'root',
  current_id: 'root',
  children: [{
    parent_id: 'root',
    current_id: 'node_233443',
    children: [{
      parent_id: 'node_233443',
      current_id: 'node_fdfd33',
      children: [],
      type: 'text',
    },
    {
      parent_id: 'node_233443',
      current_id: 'node_hd44d4',
      children: [],
      type: 'image',
    }],
    type: 'column',
  }],
  type: 'stack',
}
```

This is the solution I got.

```
const clonedNodes = structuredClone(nodes);

const recurse = (json) => {
  json.children = json.children.map((item) => {
    if(clonedNodes[item]) {
      return recurse(clonedNodes[item])
    }
  }, [])
  return json;
}

console.log(recurse(clonedNodes.root), nodes)
```

Any help to improve it please.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: @Andy I have added a solution I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the `children` arrays to the objects that correspond to the identifiers in those arrays. You may want to first clone your original object so it does not get mutated:

```js
function nest(obj) {
    const clone = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, o]) => [k, {...o}]));
    for (const node of Object.values(clone)) {
        node.children = node.children.map(id => clone[id]); 
    }
    return clone.root;
}

const data = {root: {parent_id: 'root',current_id: 'root',children: ['node_233443'],type: 'stack',},node_233443: {parent_id: 'root',current_id: 'node_233443',children: ['node_fdfd33', 'node_hd44d4'],type: 'column',},node_fdfd33: {parent_id: 'node_233443',current_id: 'node_fdfd33',children: [],type: 'text',},node_hd44d4: {parent_id: 'node_233443',current_id: 'node_hd44d4',children: [],type: 'image',},};
const result = nest(data);
console.log(result);
```